# Using PowerMock.expectNew() method could not get code coverage

Tags: constructor, mocking, code-coverage, powermock

I am trying out the example to mock a constructor provided in below link

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockconstructor

Though the Junit run  passes but the code coverage report for PersistenceManager class is zero percent .

This is   because @PrepareForTest( PersistenceManager.class ) and without this line the code fails .

How do I mock the constructor call and get 100% code coverage.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't. Or you need to be lucky.

What I am saying is: the **nature** of PowerMock(ito) is to **change** your bytecode. In other words: your unit tests are (potentially) **not** running the class files that javac/your IDE compiled. In order to do its black magic, PowerMock will **change** your class file content upon loading.

And unfortunately, code-coverage tools work they same way - they need to **instrument** the class file content in order to do their parts.

Thus one should not be surprised at all when using PowerMock leads to "zero coverage". Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not work. And the really bad part: you will probably have a very **hard** time to find a solution to that specific problem. There are various bugs around for that, for example this [one](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/422); and as said: sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Very much depends on what you are doing; and what frameworks you are using.

So, the essential non-answer - look into your need to use PowerMock. You see, chances are that you simply wrote untestable/hard-to-test production code. And now you think you need the big PowerMock hammer to fix that **design** problem in your code. Instead: learn how to create **testable** code, for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79). And then re-structure your production code, and get rid of PowerMock. I did exactly that many months ago; and I never regretted for a second to have done so. Now I rely on EasyMock/Mokito ... and code coverage *just works* for me.